# Gravity as a river

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

I understand that gravity is viewed as flowing as a river pushing objects down on the body of a planet. If that is the case and earth is a sphere, where does the gravity go when it hits the center of the planet? Does it get compressed? Is it destroyed?

Comment: Gravity is curvature of spacetime, not a river. The river descrition is very strange to say the least, where do you have that from?

Comment: This may be (yet another) bad analogy (it is, and a real stinker at that), but it appears in popular explanations of GR.

Comment: Although the OP's description isn't very good, the river model is sometimes used to describe the "flow of three space" e.g. [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0419)

Comment: Yes, rivers flow from the mountains due to gravity. They end up in the sea and never hit the centre of the planet.

Comment: I guess he has been mislead by Michio Kaku's misleading popula r   -   science explanation of general relativity.

Answer (score 5):

I take it you're referring to the river analogy that's sometimes used in connection with [Painleve Gullstrand coordinates](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060).

That is often applied to a black hole, where the "river" is a fanciful description of the "flow" of space into the black hole.  This flow increases as you approach the horizon, at which point its speed is the speed of light.

You're worried that if we apply this to an object like a planet, where the surface isn't inside its Schwarzschild radius, that the thing that's flowing in the river, i.e space, would somehow "pile up" at the planet surface or center?  There is no problem with this as spacetime points are not physical objects, but mathematical abstractions.

The apparent "flow" of space is just a way of describing the way you associate points on a slice of space with points on the slice of space an instant of time later.  This flow is the shift vector you get when express your spacetime metric in the form defined in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22204/lorentz-invariance-of-the-3-1-decomposition-of-spacetime#_=_).

Comment: How can we be sure that gravitons are merely mathematical abstractions?  Even without piling up, there is the question of what occurs specifically at the center of a mass.  Do gravitons exist?  Do they turn into radio waves?  Do they disperse as heat?  Or are they merely the result of a curvature of space/spacetime?  And how do you ascertain this conclusion?  Greatly anticipating your response.